# Mode of an updated array

Tags: java, algorithm

I have an array A and have to find mode the array after each of the m steps. In each step one element of the array is changed. How can I efficiently find the mode after each change. I calculate the initial mode using following code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;

class mode {
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int N = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        long[] A = new long[N + 1];
        HashMap<Long, Integer> hm = new HashMap<Long, Integer>();
        for (long i = 0; i <= (long)N; i++) {
            hm.put(i, 0);
        }
        hm.put((long)0, 0);
        String[] s = br.readLine().split(" ");
        for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
            A[i] = Long.parseLong(s[i - 1]);
            int res = hm.get(A[i]) + 1;
            hm.put(A[i], res);
        }
        int countM = 0;
        long M = hm.get(A[0]);
        for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
            if (hm.get(A[i]) >= countM) {
                if (A[i] > M) {
                    M = A[i];
                }
                countM = hm.get(A[i]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(M);
    }
}
```

For example let the initial array be {1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 4, 5, 1, 3, 2}. Then initial mode is 3. Now I change the fifth element to 2. Now the mode becomes 2. Again I change fourth element of the already changed array into 1. The the mode becomes 1. I want to find the mode after each change.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What is the output you want to have?

Comment: Let the initial array be {1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 4, 5, 1, 3, 2}. Then initial mode is 3. Now I change the fifth element to 2. Now the mode becomes 2. Again I change fourth element of the already changed array into 1. The the mode becomes 1. I want to find the mode after each change.

Comment: Then please add the information into the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store pairs `(number_of_occurrences, value)` in a `TreeSet` and update it every time you change the initial array(at most 2 pairs are changed, thus it takes `O(log N)` time). The answer is always the largest element in `TreeSet`(you can get it using `last` method).

Comment: I am not familiar with TreeSet. Can you give a snippet?

Comment: @user2784016 I think reading JavaDoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html is the easiest way to learn how to use it.